# troubleshooting scrollbar blocked

Tags: html, css

I don't know much about HTML/CSS. I am using a framework (Witty) that generates my html/js/css.

I have a div like follow:

```
[...]
<div style="overflow:scroll ; height:600px">
    <svg [...] height="4000" width="6000">...</svg>
</div>
```

The vertical scroll works fine
The horizontal looks fine (present and enabled) but I can't move it (tested on both latest firefox and chromium).

Problem:
The previous div is in a middle of a bunch of others, and I have no idea of how to troubleshoot that. No error in the dev console.

thanks

Comment: Can you create an example page for us to look at? From what you provide everything seems to be fine.

Comment: The question is not about how to solve the problem but how to troubleshoot/debug the situation. What would be the first things you would try? (In this case, using tilt shown that they was a div on top of my scroll bar)